# Does "hieroglyph" only refer to the ancient Egyptian form of writing or to any writing system whose basic elements represent words?

Tags: meaning, nouns

If somebody refers to Chinese or Japanese characters as *hieroglyphs* are they right or wrong? Aren't there many hieroglyphic writing systems? If somebody says *hieroglyphs* refers only to Ancient Egyptian writing are they merely pedantic or just plain wrong?

---

I know there are quite a few other terms used for Chinese and Japanese characters (han character, hanja, hanzi, ideogram, ideograph, kanji, pictogram, pictograph, sinogram, sinograph...). And I know that those characters used to be used in Korea and Vietnam, but I don't want to get sidetracked and focus just on the applicability of this term, not whether there are better or less ambiguous or more precise or more technical terms.

Comment: I believe "glyph" is the word you're looking for.

Comment: I assume you mean the technical term, not the term of abuse for anything that's [hard to comprehend](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hieroglyphic#Noun).

Comment: I definitely mean the technical term though if it's used in slightly different ways by different people I'm not sure if all such uses would qualify as technical \-:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Egyptian hieroglyphs are the most popular, but the word hieroglyph is of Greek origin ("sacred carvings") and can refer to the characters of several other logographic writing systems:

- [Anatolian Hieroglyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatolian_hieroglyphs)
- [Cretan Hieroglyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretan_hieroglyphs)
- [Olmec Hieroglyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olmec_hieroglyphs)

And [more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hieroglyph).

Answer (score 7):

I believe the more general term is **logogram**, meaning a symbol primarily denoting a *word* (or phrase) rather than a *letter*. But words and letters are slippery concepts themselves, so that wouldn't be a hard-and-fast distinction.

Anyway, I'm happy enough using *logogram* to include Chinese *pictograms*, or whatever else you want to call them, as well as various *hieroglyphs*. But I'm not so comfortable saying *hieroglyph* includes the Chinese symbols.

Comment: I've always associated hieroglyphic writing more with marks being carved or cut into the writing surface (which may be easily done in soft clay intended to dry and harden after writing). I think the etymology of the word supports this association. Chinese writing is evocative of brush-and-ink marks on fabric, etc. (I think the Chinese invented ink first), so they have a somewhat different appearance because of the nature of how they were usually made.

Comment: *Chinese writing is evocative of brush-and-ink marks on fabric, etc.* I think this is a very good point: we call hieroglyphs hieroglyphs not because they actually have to be carved in something, but because carving is an essential element in the history of their origin. // There is also *ideogram*.

Comment: @Cerberus: Good point. I forgot ideograms. Do we not sometimes use that term to denote symbols that aren't directly translateable into *words* without recourse to excessively long phrases and caveats? In which case they don't necessarily apply to any particular writing systems, just to certain symbols in certain systems.

Comment: **logogram** means a symbol that denotes a word and both Chinese/Japanese and Egyptian sometimes use their symbols this way, but they both use their symbols much more commonly in other ways. "Hieroglyph" does seem to be *associated* with carved letters but isn't the term "inscription" better for this? The earliest known Chinese writing was scratched on bone. It has also been used for inscription in stone for centuries.

Comment: @hippietrail: I'm no archeologist, but might it not be that the earliest known Chinese writing was scratched on bone because it lasts longer? I don't know if anything like ink was around then, but anything written with it would be lucky to survive for us to identify. Anyway, whatever medium was used first in China, I don't think many people would call the marks they made *hieroglyphs*.

Comment: (I don't mean they used bone because it lasts longer, I mean that's why it's the earliest we find: anything else would be likely lost to us by now)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Just making a point that Chinese writing has been around for 1000s of years so our current associations might not be totally relevant to the meanings of various terms though it will be relevant to current usage. Also interesting that people take the "glyph = stone" part of the etymology as essential but not so with the "hiero = holy" part. Here's an interesting graph from Google ngram viewer too: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Chinese+hieroglyphs%2CJapanese+hieroglyphs%2CEgyptian+hieroglyphs%2CMayan+hieroglyphs&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: @hippietrail: Very neat, thanks. That should be in the top-rated answer (a picture paints a thousand words, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

Chinese and Japanese characters are **not** hieroglyphs. They are a mixture of pictograms, ideograms, phono-semantic compounds and others. Japanese also has two phonetic syllabaries.

Comment: Agreed - especially for modern Chinese - but I think giving such an absolute answer only reinforces the idea that hieroglyphs are solely Egyptian. It is important to note that phonetic Chinese writing evolved from a technically hieroglyphic system. As I'm sure you're well aware, I mention this only for posterity.

Comment: Well, technically they are now called *sinograms*. And I don't care about the effect this answer may or may not have on the impression that hieroglyphs are an Egyptian phenomenon. I think it's important to define the term also by what they are not, and the OP is clearly asking about whether Chinese or Japanese characters are hieroglyphs. Which they are not. Which is the entire thrust of my answer.

Comment: @Robusto: According to Wikipedia, Hieroglyphs consist of three kinds of glyphs: phonetic glyphs, including single-consonant characters that function like an alphabet; logographs, representing morphemes; and determinatives, which narrow down the meaning of logographic or phonetic words. Which of these several kinds is it that makes them **not** like the several Chinese and Japanese kinds? (And Japanese has not one but two phonetic syllabaries, but that's besides the point.)

Comment: @hippietrail: Japanese has a single syllabary, but two ways of representing the syllables: 平仮名　(ひらがな　*hiragana*)　平仮名 and　片仮名 (カタカナ *katakana*) of which I just gave you examples. *Hiragana* is the cursive phonetic system, *katakana* is the one they use for display type and foreign loan words or names.

Comment: And if you want to look up Chinese writing in Wikipedia, look at the [character formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character#Formation_of_characters) section. Then search the page for the word "hieroglyph" ...

Comment: @Robusto, hmm maybe should pose another question: does "syllabary" refer to a set of symbols or a set of sounds (-: In fact I think that's a nice seed question for the proposed "languages" site.

Comment: @hippietrail: I always understood it to be the list of syllables itself, but I just checked the dictionary and it says syllabary also refers to the written representation. So I guess you're right that Japanese has two *syllabaries* in that sense, but they themselves call *hiragana* and *katakana* collectively 五十音 (*gojuuon*), which translates into English as "the 50 sounds". There are actually not exactly 50 sounds (more if you count vocalization and consonant changes achieved by adding marks to some of the kana), but you get the idea. It's one set of sounds, two ways of writing each sound.

Comment: @Robusto Got a bone to pick? It took me one click to get from [character formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character#Formation_of_characters) to the word _hieroglyph_. Not a very compelling argument. Can you refute that 休 is, by definition, a hieroglyph? I don't think it's as black and white as you're trying to paint it.

Comment: @HaL: Looks like you're the one with a bone to pick. But you're right, the mere fact that you can get from one page to another page is not a very compelling argument. And if you say 休 (*kyuu*, meaning "rest" or "sleep") is a hieroglyph, make your case. The supposition that a writing system started off with pictograms doesn't mean it stayed there. In any case, you started off saying you agreed with my response — and now you want to peck out my liver?  お休みなさい。

Comment: @Robusto: I still agree with your answer. I was just trying to prevent someone from being put off from researching hieroglyphics further after reading your answer, that's all. No use dragging this one out. (also: 人 + 木 = 休, perhaps?)

Comment: @HaL: The point being that "man" + "tree" = "rest"? I still don't think that is a hieroglyph. I'm more persuaded that the original character for "sun" (a circle with a dot in the middle, which was directly representational of the sun) was hieroglyphic in nature. But the current character, 日, though derived from that original version, is not. How do we get from 木 ("tree", "wood") to 本 ("book" or "true" or "main" or "cylindrical object") or to 東 ("east")? Surely whatever hieroglyphic qualities the originals may have had have been long since eroded away.